# Only getting models that haven't been soft deleted

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I've added `use SoftDeletingTrait;` and `protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];` to my Laravel 4.2 model, but it still gets records that have been soft deleted even when I don't use `withTrashed()`.

For instance, if I have multiple stores then `Store::all()` and `Store::where('condition', $value)->get()` still returns deleted stores unless I add `->whereNull('deleted_at')` to both calls.

Same goes for relational tables like `Auth::user()->stores()` then I still have have to customize the `stores()` method to use `->whereNull('deleted_at')`.

What might I be doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you added `$table->softDeletes();` to your migration? What is in the database, is there a Date for a delteded model?

Comment: Yes, `$table->softDeletes();` is in the migration and there is a `deleted_at` field in the table structure.

Comment: But has a deleted model also a valide  deleted date?

Comment: For testing: make a fresh installation of laravel and try it there to make sure it has nothing to do with your current project.